# How to change pandas dataframe strings into integers?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Here I have a csv file that I am attempting to turn into all integer values, but I am not sure how to do it. I have looked at other posts but they don't seem to be working.

Here is my csv:

```
X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,PosNeg
x,x,x,x,o,o,x,o,o,positive
x,x,x,x,o,o,o,x,o,positive
x,x,x,x,o,o,o,o,x,positive
x,x,x,x,o,o,o,b,b,positive
x,x,x,x,o,o,b,o,b,positive
x,x,x,x,o,o,b,b,o,positive
x,x,x,x,o,b,o,o,b,positive
x,x,x,x,o,b,o,b,o,positive
x,x,x,x,o,b,b,o,o,positive
x,x,x,x,b,o,o,o,b,positive
x,x,x,x,b,o,o,b,o,positive
x,x,x,x,b,o,b,o,o,positive
x,x,x,o,x,o,x,o,o,positive
x,x,x,o,x,o,o,x,o,positive
x,x,x,o,x,o,o,o,x,positive
x,x,x,o,x,o,o,b,b,positive
x,x,x,o,x,o,b,o,b,positive
x,x,x,o,x,o,b,b,o,positive
x,x,x,o,x,b,o,o,b,positive
x,x,x,o,x,b,o,b,o,positive
x,x,x,o,x,b,b,o,o,positive
```

I would like to transform it into something like this:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the criteria for this? Explain the pattern please so we can help you.

Comment: which chars should get mapped to which numbers, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the replace() function of your pandas Dataframe to first replace all "x" values with 1 and then afterwards "o" with 0 as such:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(r"<PATH>")
>>> df
   1  2  3
0  x  x  o
1  x  x  o
2  o  o  x
3  x  o  x

>>> df = df.replace("x", 1)
>>> df
   1  2  3
0  1  1  o
1  1  1  o
2  o  o  1
3  1  o  1

>>> df = df.replace("o", 0)
>>> df
   1  2  3
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  1
```

[Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: After this, how would I convert it into training data and testing data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map function with a simple lambda function like this:

```
df['X1'].map(lambda x:  
if x == 'o':
  return 0
if x == 'x':
  return 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `replace`

For the whole DataFrame with chained `replace`

```
df = df.replace('x', 1).replace('o', 0)
```

Or you can pass a `dict` to `replace`

```
df.replace({'x': 1, 'o': 0})
```

---

#### `apply`

For a single column

```
df['x1'].apply(lambda l: 0 if l == 'o' else 1)
```

---

#### `applymap`

For all columns (if the results should be binary [0 or 1])

```
df.applymap(lambda l: 0 if l == 'o' else 1)
```

Comment: Use a `dict` in the call to `replace`. `df.replace({'x': 1, 'o': 0, 'b': -1})`

Answer (score 0):

The pandas [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function accepts a dictionary that maps from one value to another. 
 However, since you are starting with a Data Frame of strings and you want integers, you should the columns to a numeric datatype with the method [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).

```
df.replace({'x': 1, 
            'o': 0,
            'b': -1,  
            'positive': 2, 
            'negative': -2}).astype(np.int16)
```